# spring jndi values from JNDI tree

Tags: spring, jboss, weblogic, jndi

I am working with spring 3.0 and within our JBoss application server I perform a JNDI lookup to a remote WebLogic application server.  The properties to connect to the WebLogic JNDI server are contained in a properties file called **soa.properties**.  Here is what the **spring-config.xml** looks like to initialize the **JndiTemplate** bean

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:soa.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="soaJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${soa.provider.initial}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${soa.provider.url}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${soa.security.principal}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${soa.security.credentials}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

This works fine for pulling my values out of the **soa.properties** file, but what I would rather do is pull the WebLogic JNDI connection values out of the JBoss JNDI tree.

My problem appears to be with the initialization of the InitialContext object that requires Properties for initialization.

I put all of my JNDI String values for WebLogic JNDI connection into the JBoss JNDI.  Below is the code I am using to pull the values out and initialize **JndiTemplate** bean.

```
<bean id="soaUrl" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName"       value="soa/provider/url" />
</bean>
<bean id="soaFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName"       value="soa/provider/connection/factory" />
</bean>
<bean id="soaInitial" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName"       value="soa/provider/initial" />
</bean>
<bean id="soaPrincipal" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName"       value="soa/security/principal" />
</bean>
<bean id="soaCredential" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName"       value="soa/security/credential" />
</bean>
<bean id="testsoaJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
  <property name="environment">
    <map>
      <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial"  value-ref="soaUrl" />
      <entry key="java.naming.provider.url"     value-ref="soaFactory" />
      <entry key="java.naming.provider.initial" value-ref="soaInitial" />
      <entry key="java.security.principal"      value-ref="soaPrincipal" />
      <entry key="java.security.credential"     value-ref="soaCredential" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

My application comes up with these beans created, but when I use **testsoaJndiTemplate** with say **soaConnectionFactory** like so it boms.

```
<bean id="soaConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate"   ref="testsoaJndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName"       value="${soa.provider.connection.factory.name}" />
</bean>
```

The error is so cryptic it does make any sense. 
Thanks

Comment: 12% acceptance what does that mean?

Comment: It means that you did not accept an answer to 88% of questions you asked.